# Controller Constructor with primitive parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In an attempt to refactor code, I have recently changed my Controller to be constructed by taking string instead of IConfiguration and that is coming from another controller.

**StatusController.cs**

```
public class StatusController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase
{
    
    protected StatusDAL status_dal;
    public StatusController(string connectionString)
    {
        status_dal = new StatusDAL(connectionString);
    }
 }
```

This particular controller is being called by another controller

**HVIRCalcController.cs**

```
public class HVIRCalcController : BaseServicesController
{

    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public HVIRCalcController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        
        _connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("toolboxConnectionStrWPS");
        
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostTask(int service_id, [FromBody]HVIRServiceRequestParams hvir_params)
    {
         StatusAck sack = new HVIR_Calc_Engine(_connectionString).BatchCalc(hvir_params);

     }
}
```

**HVIRCalcEngine.cs**

```
public class HVIR_Calc_Engine
{
    private string _connectionString;

    public HVIR_Calc_Engine(string connectionString)
    {
        //this.config = config;
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        status_dal = new StatusDAL(connectionString);
        pg_dal = new PostgresDAL(connectionString);

    }

    public StatusAck BatchCalc(HVIRServiceRequestParams hvirparams)
    {
       StatusAck statusack = new StatusController(_connectionString).PostStatusRecord();
    }
}
```

It gives me the error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'WPS_WebAPI.Controllers.StatusController'

Is there a way to avoid passing IConfiguration from HVIRCalcController all the way to StatusController?

Comment: use IOptions pattern with a strongly typed configuration

Comment: Also Reference [Dependency Injection Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/)